# Cannot use Keychain in Xcode9 tests

Tags: swift, keychain, xcode9

I have a few unit tests to verify that the way I work with Keychain is correct and data are in same form when I load them.

Tests were running ok until update to XCode 9. At the moment, KeychainService return -50 (not saved).

According to this [question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86961), it was solved by adding Host to unit tests. However, my tests are in framework project and there is no app to use as a host.

```
let query = [
    kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
    kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
    kSecValueData as String   : data ] as [String : Any]

SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)

SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
```

What is recommended solution? I expect just some configuration in XCode, moving tests into app is not a proper solution for me.

Comment: any related code-snippet...? I have a perfectly functioning _KeyChain_ access in Xcode9, Swift4; no anomalies have been experienced here. you may also take a look on the official [GenericKeychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) project at Apple's site for comparing to yours and finding the glitch.

Comment: I added code sample. Calling `SecItemAdd` return -50

Comment: To clarify - KeyChain is working, but not in unit tests

Answer (score 14):

Starting with Xcode 9, test bundles require a host app to access the keychain from within the iOS simulator, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46317131/5082444.

Simply add an app target and set it as the host application for your unit test bundle.